# How do you check if a Web is an AppWeb using CSOM?

Tags: client-object-model

With **CSOM**, how can I test if a web is the container for a SharePoint hosted app, equivalent of [SPWeb.IsAppWeb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.isappweb%28v=office.15%29.aspx)?

Comment: Actually looking for the same thing myself right now. one thing I've found: web.get_appInstanceId() will return the guid of the installed app or "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" if it's a normal web.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Looking at the documentation it seems like a viable approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is the implementation of SPWeb.IsAppWeb (via Reflector)

```
public bool IsAppWeb
{
    get
    {
        return (this.AppInstanceId != Guid.Empty);
    }
}
```

Comment: Kinda makes you wonder why they couldn't have implemented that in CSOM #hmmmm

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the WebTemplate property of the Web object. The WebTemplate value will be "APP" if it is an App Web.

```
// Exclude any App Webs
if (subweb.WebTemplate.Equals("APP")) continue;
```